Time dependent Schrödinger equation for dual state
This might be a stupid question, but how does one derive the TDSE (time-dependent Schrödinger equation) for the dual state $\langle \Psi(t)|$?
Here is my try:
TDSE:    $i\hbar\  \partial_t |\Psi(t)\rangle = \hat{H} |\Psi(t) \rangle$. Now we just take the adjoint on both sides:

$(\hat{H}|\Psi(t)\rangle)^\dagger\stackrel{?}{=} |\Psi(t)\rangle^\dagger\hat{H}^\dagger=\langle\Psi(t)| \hat{H}$

$(i\hbar\ \partial_t|\Psi(t)\rangle)^\dagger\stackrel{?}{=}|\Psi(t)\rangle^\dagger \partial_t\  ^\dagger(i\hbar)^\dagger= \langle\Psi(t)|\partial_t \ (-i\hbar)=\frac{\hbar}{i}\langle\Psi(t)|\partial_t$


So, I get:
$$(i\hbar\  \partial_t |\Psi(t)\rangle)^\dagger = (\hat{H} |\Psi(t) \rangle)^\dagger \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad\frac{\hbar}{i}\langle\Psi(t)|\partial_t=\langle\Psi(t)| \hat{H}$$ which seems weird? Is this correct or wrong? Shouldn't $\langle \Psi(t) |$ evolve in time as well? I would expect something like $(\cdot\cdot\cdot)\partial_t \langle\Psi(t)| = (\cdot\cdot\cdot)$. Or do I have to further manipulate the equation to get the final result?
The step $\stackrel{?}{=}$ is where I'm uncertain. When can I swap the order and when can't I? I just assumed the operator rule: $(\hat{A}\hat{B})^\dagger=\hat{B}^\dagger \hat{A}^\dagger$ could be used like this $(\hat{A}|\Psi\rangle)^\dagger=\langle \Psi| \hat{A}^\dagger$, which seems right? $(\langle a|\hat{A}| a\rangle)^\dagger=|a\rangle^\dagger \hat{A}^\dagger \langle a|^\dagger=\langle a|\hat{A}^\dagger|a\rangle$
Can $\langle \Psi | \partial_t$ be interpereted as $\partial_t$ acting on $\langle \Psi |$?
I think the thing is that when we have $\langle a|\hat{A}| a \rangle$ we can do either $\langle a, \hat{A}| a \rangle$ or $\langle a | \hat{A},a \rangle$, where we interperet $\langle a, \hat{A}|=\langle a|\hat{A}$ as one bra or $|\hat{A},a\rangle=\hat{A}|a\rangle$ as one ket.Is this the solution? That we interperet $\langle \Psi|\partial_t$ as the bra $\langle\Psi,\partial_t|$?
Any comments to clear up my misunderstanding would be helpful. I think this probably is very simple and I'm just missing something obvious here (?).

This for sure has been asked here before...in any case, my comments here should (perhaps some modifications are needed if e.g. the Hamiltonian is unbounded; but the idea is the same). The problem you have seems partly/mostly due to the use of Dirac notation, which IMHO is not good, especially if one doesn't know what exactly is happening...

...to add: You should not think of the derivative as an operator on the Hilbert space (this has been asked and answered/discussed here on PSE also quite often; if you search for it you should find a few good posts); so I'd recommend to not write something like $\partial_t^\dagger$.
